# Preg_replace, replacing just the part of pattern in ( )?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Sorry for this basic question, but I've been looking over all the info about preg_replace I can find and I still can't figure this out.. I have a large string, like this, for example:

```
  $string= '# tjs { fassdaf } #fsk { fssf} # fskff { casf }';
```

And when I do this, it replaces the entire pattern, not just the part in ( ) as I expect it to do.. I am wondering how I can just replace the part in ( ).. thanks

```
  $pattern= '/#.*tjs.*\{.*(.*)\}/imsU';
  $replacement= "test";
  $return_string = preg_replace ($string, $pattern, $replacement );
```

expected replaced string:

```
'# tjs {test} #fsk { fssf} # fskff { casf }';
```

Comment: Can you post the expected replaced string too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pattern= '/(#\s*tjs\s*\{\s*)(.*?)(\s*\})/imsU';
$replacement= "test";
$return_string = preg_replace($pattern,'$1'.$replacement.'$3',$string);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, I saw the mention of $1 and $3 in an example on the php preg_replace page but they used some strange syntax with { so I think that threw me off

Comment: you can also use \1 and \3 instead of $1 and $3